# going from command window (as script) to function

Tags: matlab

the program is working perfectly but when i am changing it to function the follwing error is beeing displayed:

```
     [Parent1index, Parent1Position, alldcel] = Parent1n(TotalnoOfGrids, noOfNodes, Penalties, test)
     ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

     Error in ==> Parent1n at 10
     [~,index]=min(alldcel{t});
```

Comment: No need to backtick the code when it's indented properly, thanks for trying though!

Comment: when i idented, it did not put in grey background and was not clear. Thanks for the comment

Comment: just to check, can you make it a script, execute command "clear all" in the command line and start the script?

Comment: @Daniyar yes it is working but if i call as function other error poped: ??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. Error in ==> Parent1n at 12 pocket=test{t}; oh no same error again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok with this code the functiion worked:`if Penalties{t}(r)> 0;
alldcel {t}(r)=alldcel{t}(r);
else alldcel {t}(r)=inf;` but interchanging if statement with else did not

Answer (score 1):

Because `alldcell{t}` may not exist for some values of `t` if the condition to assign values to it in

```
if Penalties{t}(r)== 0;
   alldcel{t}(r)=inf;
end
```

is never satisfied. Assume for some `t` that all values of `Penalties{t}` are different than zero.  Then you would never assign `inf` to `alldcell{t}`.  That means, you are only extending the cell array `alldcell` when `Penalties{t}` is zero for some `r`. If the condition is never satisfied, `alldcell{t}` will not exist and asking for it will give you a cell array error.

You should at least initialize it using `alldcell = cell(TotalnoOfGrids,1)`.

Also, comparing for equality to zero using `a==0` is not a good idea. You should use `abs(a)<tol` for some small value `tol`.